# Unable to install CSharpier globally with dotnet CLI

Tags: dotnet-cli

I am unable to successfully run the command to install CSharpier globally. I am running the command as given in the docs and I get the following error.

The command: `dotnet install -g csharpier`

The error:

```
The service index for source https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'csharpier' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool.
```

Comment: What nuget feed(s) are you using. As far as I can tell csharpier should be in the standard Nuget.org feed.

Comment: The docs also say you should install using `dotnet tool install csharpier` instead of `dotnet install -g csharpier` not sure if that makes a difference though.

Comment: @phuzi the -g is the global flag. It will install it globally.

Comment: @phuzi I have the standard nuget feed as well as the Telerik feed. Not sure why it can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, also have the Telerik feed so realised this must be related. Go to visual studio and uncheck Telerik feed temporarily. Then run the command again and it should work.